# Propagating EF Core BaseContext to sub-classes via Dependancy Injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core

I’ve a fairly standard AspNet Core API solution which has the following in the ConfigureServices of its Startup.cs

`services.AddContext<BaseContext>(Options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));`

I can then use Dependency Injection to ‘pass’ the BaseContext to the controller.

What I would then like to do is use that same BaseContext in any classes that I `new` from methods within the controller (and then on to any classes I `new` from that class, and so on).

Do I need to just pass the BaseContext as a parameter to the constructor to each class (which seems a pain and means passing it to classes that don’t directly need it but will just pass it on), or is it possible to pull the BaseContext out of the ServiceProvider somehow so I only have it available where it’s actually needed?

I’ve read up on Constructor Injection etc. but I don’t think they match what I’m trying to do.

Comment: Creating new classes with business logic is a code smell. Could you please provide your code?

Comment: @bdongus either we are talking at cross-purposes or I seriously misunderstand the single responsibility principle but business logic not being in separate classes would be code smell to me. I'll add some details of the process flow in the post when I get a chance.

Comment: How does constructor injection not match with what you're trying to do? Your other classes can be exposed to your controller via interfaces, and then DI can inject the BaseContext to the actual implemented class.

Comment: @jimbo-ish My comment is only based on you using "new" and having the need to pass the BaseContext to those instances. Just guessing: The passing of your BaseContext and creating new instances needing it can be avoided by injecting those instances and let the DI container do the job.